# Average result for a unique ID on the same date

Tags: r

I have a lab dataset where some patients have multiple recordings on the same date. I am trying to take the average of the results and produce that as my final result for that particular date. I used the approach mentioned below, however, it doesn't seem to work.

```
ACCT <- c(4333,3234,4232,1313,1341,4244,3211)
TEST_DATE <- c('2016-04-01', '2016-04-01', '2016-04-01', '2016-04-01','2016-04-01','2016-04-01','2016-04-01')
RESULTS <- c(1.4,1.7,1.2,1.8,1.5,1.7)

df <- data.frame(ACCT,TEST_DATE,RESULTS)

df$TEST_DATE <- as.POSIX(df$TEST_DATE)
```

Creating non duplicate rows based on ACCT and TEST_DATE. This will give me accounts that don't have duplicate dates:

```
df_nonduplicates <- df %>% group_by(ACCT,TEST_DATE) %>% filter(!n()>1)
```

Creating a data frame that gives me ACCTS that have duplicate TEST_DATE's:

```
df_duplicates <- df %>% group_by(ACCT,TEST_DATE) %>% filter(n()>1)
```

Trying to take the average result of ACCT's that have more than one result on a TEST_DATE:

```
df_cleaned_duplicates <- df_duplicates %>% group_by(ACCT) %>%mutate(avg_result=mean(as.numeric(df_duplicates$RESULTS, NA.rm=TRUE))) %>% select(ACCT, TEST_DATE, avg_result)
```

This is giving me NA values for the entire avg_result column. I'm not able to understand why.

Joining the two datasets:

```
final_result <- rbind(df_nonduplicates, df_cleaned_duplicates)
```

Comment: Not clear about the object `b_creatinine_duplicates`.  Your example is not working

Comment: Also `df_creatinine` is not defined.

Comment: I just edited my code, let me know if it works now!

Comment: @Meghna can you check the input data `df <- data.frame(ACCT,TEST_DATE,RESULTS)
Error in data.frame(ACCT, TEST_DATE, RESULTS) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 6`

Comment: In the example, there are no groups with more than one row

Comment: In the real example, if there are dupes, then you could do this without subsetting `df %>% group_by(ACCT, TEST_DATE) %>% mutate(avg_result = if(n() > 1) mean(RESULTS, na.rm = TRUE) else NA_real_)`

Comment: Meghna, please make sure that the example you share is working. Create a new R session and try to run the code before posting and confirm that it works to save time for both us and you. After you have correct input example, add an expected output for the data shared so that we can verify that our answer works as expected before posting.